# How do I detect Alt in a Metro (Windows 8) application?

Tags: c#, keyboard, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am trying to figure out how to detect that Alt has been pressed.

The Keyboard class has been deprecated and the KeyUp/Down events, in their EventArgs, do not contain a virtual key corresponding to Alt.

How do I detect it then?

Answer (score 3):

According to Companynerd255 in the Community additions section of the VirtualKey page on MSDN, you can still get the missing keys:

> Some keys missing from enumeration Some of the keys on the keyboard
>   are missing from VirtualKey, including the Equals key and a few
>   others. However, these keys still trigger key events in WinRT, so a
>   simple workaround exists:
>
> Find out what the integer keycode for that key is (e.g. for Equals,
>   it's 187) Cast that integer as a VirtualKey when checking for that key
>   (e.g. (VirtualKey)187)

Found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.virtualkey.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Bleh. Apparently the "Menu" VirtualKey code is for "Alt"

I guess because it brings up the menu.

If you go to the [old MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx), it actually says just that:

> Menu  The ALT key.

However, in the [new documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.virtualkey.aspx), it does not say that:

> Menu | menu 18 The menu key or button.

Ah well....